# Entity Framework Core 1.0 RTM add migration failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-1.0

Since the update of Core 1.0 RTM, I now cannot update the database:

> dotnet ef migrations add CreatedJobcards

I now get this error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

My project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Kendo.Mvc": "2016.2.630",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
The same error occurs also on the next commands:

> dotnet ef database update 0
>
> dotnet ef migrations remove

UPDATE 2:  Including the Database Context file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using mysite.com.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace mysite.com.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, Guid>
    {

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
            {
                b.Property(u => u.Id).HasColumnName("UserId").HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
            });

            builder.Entity<Role>(b =>
            {
                b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
            });


            builder.Entity<Attachment>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.AttachmentID)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.AdminOnly).HasDefaultValueSql("0");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.EntityName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);
            });

            builder.Entity<Employee>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeID)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateOfBirth).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeNumber).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.ID_Passport_No).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Position).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Surname).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Organisation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrganisationID)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Employee_Organisation");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.TestCycle)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TestCycleID)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Employee_TestCycle");
            });

            builder.Entity<Examiner>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(a => a.User)
                .WithMany(b => b.Examiners);

                entity.Property(e => e.ExaminerID)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.CompanyName).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.CompanyTelephone).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.CompanyURL).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Facebook).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.FirstName).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Google).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Instagram).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.LastName).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.LinkedIn).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Mobile).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Skype).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Twitter).HasMaxLength(255);
            });

            builder.Entity<Note>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.NoteID)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.EntityName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.NoteText)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("Note");
            });

            builder.Entity<Organisation>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(a => a.User)
                .WithMany(b => b.Organisations);

                entity.Property(e => e.OrganisationID)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.Branch).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.BranchCode).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.GPSCoords).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.Telephone).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.VATNo).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.WebSite).HasMaxLength(255);

            });

            builder.Entity<OrganisationContact>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.OrganisationContactID)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Surname).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Telephone).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Type).HasColumnType("nchar(10)");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Organisation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.OrganisationContact)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrganisationID)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_OrganisationContact_Organisation");
            });

            builder.Entity<Polygraph>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.PolygraphID)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();


                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.NextTestDate).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.Place).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Reason).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.TestResult).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Examiner)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Polygraph)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ExaminerID)

                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Polygraph_Examiner");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Employee)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Polygraph)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeeID)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Polygraph_Employee");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.PolygraphType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Polygraph)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PolygraphTypeID)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Polygraph_PolygraphType");
            });
            builder.Entity<Photo>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.PhotoID)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            });

            builder.Entity<TestCycle>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(maxLength: 255);

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayOrder).HasDefaultValueSql(sql: "0");
            });

            builder.Entity<PolygraphType>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.PolygraphTypeID)
                    .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            });

            builder.Entity<Jobcard>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.JobcardID)
                   .HasDefaultValueSql(sql: "newsequentialid()")
                   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).HasColumnType(typeName: "datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.BookingCount).IsRequired(required: true);

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType(typeName: "datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Reason).HasMaxLength(maxLength: 255);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Organisation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Jobcards)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrganisationId)
                    .HasConstraintName(name: "FK_Jobcard_Organisation");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Examiner)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Jobcards)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ExaminerId)
                    .HasConstraintName(name: "FK_Jobcard_Examiner");
            });
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }





        public virtual DbSet<Attachment> Attachment { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Examiner> Examiner { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Note> Note { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Organisation> Organisation { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrganisationContact> OrganisationContact { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Polygraph> Polygraph { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PolygraphType> PolygraphType { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TestCycle> TestCycle { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Photo> Photo { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Jobcard> Jobcard { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your DbContext also ?

Comment: @VolkanSeçkinAkbayır  I can, but seeing that the application builds without issue and the error also occurs in running 'dotnet ef database update 0', i really do not think it is anything to do with the **dbContext**.
I will however update the post to include that as well

Comment: So , do DbContext has a dependency via constructor injection ?

Comment: Nope.  Just prettty standard.  I updated the post to include the DbContext

Comment: Because you are using the 1.0.0 version tools should be `preview2` and not preview1. You should also remove imports from tools. Finally, after you fix these issues I would recommend cleaning NuGet caches with `nuget.exe locals -Clear all`

Comment: You also have publish-iis tool configured as your postpublish script but you have not included this tool in your project.json. You will see an error during publish (but this is a separate issue)

Comment: @Pawel  Thank you for your help.  The error above is now gone.  I have cleared the NuGet Cache and have removed the imports from tools before.  Also included IISIntegration.Tools now for Publish (removed it before to reduce the packages).  But now it is compiling and then it just shows this message:
_Could not invoke this command on the project. Check that the version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools in "tools" and "dependencies" are the same. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for more details._

Comment: Thank you @Pawel.  It is sorted now.  I had to redo the process again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using version 1.0.0 (and not rc2) your tools should be `preview2` and not `preview1`. You also don't need `imports` anymore. After you fix your project.json I would recommend cleaning NuGet caches with `nuget.exe locals -Clear all`
As a side note - you have `publish-iis` configured to run as a postpublish script but you don't have this tool in your project so you will get an error when publishing since `dotnet` won't be able to find this tool. You need to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISIntegration.Tools` to your tools section (again `preview2` and no `imports`)